# how to sum list in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, sum

I want to add up the list but in the API the data is in the form of a String so when I change it to a String the result only displays the array in the widget.
how do i solve this problem.

I've tried changing it in another way but the error still occurs so I'm having trouble experiencing this problem.

```dart
    class NilaiMahasiswaPage extends StatefulWidget {
    const NilaiMahasiswaPage({super.key});

    @override
    State<NilaiMahasiswaPage> createState() => _NilaiMahasiswaPageState();
    }

    class _NilaiMahasiswaPageState extends State<NilaiMahasiswaPage> {
    List<int> listitems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    int semester = 1;
    List<Data> data = [];

    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData(semester);
    }

    fetchData(int smt) async {
    final apiResponse = await NilaiMhsProvider().getTranskripNilai(smt);
    setState(() {
      data = (apiResponse.data!);
    });
    } 

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final listMutu = data.map((e) => int.tryParse(e.nilaiIndeksAkhir ?? '') ?? 0).toList();
    final listSks = data.map((e) => e.sks ?? '').toList();
    // print(listMutu);
    Widget header() {
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 6,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Total SKS : ',
                style: bold5,
              ),
              Text(
                ' $listSks',
                style: bold5,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Total Mutu : ',
                style: bold5,
              ),
              Text(
                ' ${listMutu.sum}',
                style: bold5,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Indeks Prestasi (IP) : ',
                style: bold5,
              ),
              Text(
                '3.21',
                style: bold5,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Indeks Prestasi Komulatif (IPK) : ',
                style: bold5,
              ),
              Text(
                '3.66',
                style: bold5,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Text(
            'Pilih Semester',
            style: regular5,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 8),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                  spreadRadius: 1,
                  blurRadius: 9,
                  offset: const Offset(
                    1,
                    2,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton(
                hint: const Text('Pilih Semester'),
                value: semester,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      semester = value!;
                    },
                  );
                  fetchData(value!);
                },
                items: listitems.map(
                  (itemone) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: itemone,
                      child: Text(
                        itemone.toString(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 14,
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    Widget body() {
      return Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            getSum() {
              final sks = (data[index].sks);
              final mutu = int.tryParse(data[index].nilaiIndeksAkhir ?? '');
              var result = (sks ?? '0') * (mutu ?? 0);
              // print('Hasil dari penjumlahan adalah : $result');
              return result;
            }

            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 6,
                top: 6,
              ),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(8),
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                      spreadRadius: 1,
                      blurRadius: 9,
                      offset: const Offset(
                        1,
                        2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        data[index].nmMk ?? '',
                        style: bold5,
                      ),
                      const Divider(),
                      Table(
                        defaultColumnWidth: const FlexColumnWidth(),
                        border: const TableBorder(
                          verticalInside: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        children: [
                          TableRow(children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Kode MK',
                                  style: regular7,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Huruf Mutu',
                                  style: regular7,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Angka Mutu',
                                  style: regular7,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Mutu SKS',
                                  style: regular7,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Nilai Mutu',
                                  style: regular7,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ]),
                          TableRow(
                            children: [
                              Column(children: [
                                Text(
                                  '${data[index].kodeMk}',
                                  style: bold6,
                                )
                              ]),
                              Column(children: [
                                Text(
                                  '${data[index].nilaiHurufUts}',
                                  style: bold6,
                                )
                              ]),
                              Column(children: [
                                Text(
                                  '${data[index].nilaiIndeksAkhir}',
                                  style: bold6,
                                )
                              ]),
                              Column(children: [
                                Text(
                                  '${data[index].sks}',
                                  style: bold6,
                                ),
                              ]),
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    getSum(),
                                    // ' ${sumMutu}',
                                    style: bold6,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: CustomAppbar(
          title: 'Transkrip Nilai',
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 20,
          left: 18,
          right: 18,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // footer(),
            header(),
            body(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getSum` function should as..

```
        getSum() {
          final sks = int.tryParse(data[index].sks?.toString() ?? '');
          final mutu = int.tryParse(data[index].nilaiIndeksAkhir ?? '');
          var result = (sks ?? 0) * (mutu ?? 0);
          // print('Hasil dari penjumlahan adalah : $result');
          return result.toString();
        }
```

Make sure `nilaiIndeksAkhir` should not be `null`. I'm seeing few items are `null`.

Comment: it worked, for the card.
but for the number of headers it hasn't worked
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gg6DnwGNs6HaclnvbzfaGV49Qwpn6-m4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That is the display of `listSks`, but you used `listMutu` for showing `total Mutu`.

Comment: how do i sum listSks?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IWsfuNhHBh2IrcORfgYF7DLc5lgrBtew/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `final listSks = data.map((e) => int.tryParse(e.sks ?? '0') ?? 0).toList();` Try replace with this line

Comment: it worked, yesterday I wrote a similar code, but I wrote the wrong String.
Thank You.